# How to set top-center position of component via code?

Tags: java, android

I need to generate users view through java code and I cannot set position of my TextView. I want to set component on top of LinearLayout and center it, It would look like this if I would use xml:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

My code is:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
test = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
test.append("test");
activityTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.addView(activityTitle, params);
setContentView(layout);
```

And here's output:

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Use `layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.TOP);` to your `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.TOP);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
test = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
test.append("test");
activityTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.addView(activityTitle, params);
setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutstate = new LinearLayout(this);

  linearLayoutstate.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  linearLayoutstate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  TextView stateTitletv = new TextView(this);

  stateTitletv.setText("test");

  linearLayoutstate.addView(stateTitletv);

  linearLayoutstate.addView(state_valuetv);

  LL_SelectedFilters.addView(linearLayoutstate,layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change width of your TextView to `MATCH_PARENT`

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```